# Best way to implement django model that need several layers of relation

Tags: python, django, model

I am building a quiz application using Django and can’t figure out the best way of building the models in regard to question category.

A question will be related to one domain, for example it could be IT, Aviation or Science etc. This will be unique field.

A topic will relate to a domain, for example meteorology could be part of the Aviation domain but could also be part of Science domain. For this reason this can’t be a unique field.

A sub-topic will directly relate to a topic (and consequently a domain), for example climate or atmosphere would be part of Aviation->Meteorology

Here are some example of combination of categories

Aviation->Meteorology->Climate

Aviation->Meteorology->Atmosphere

Aviation->Mass and Balance

The sub-topic is optional but all combination must be unique i.e. I can’t have two “Aviation->Meteorology->Climate” or two “Aviation->Mass and Balance”

I am not sure how to implement this in the models but was thinking of doing one of the two solutions below

1)

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.TextField('What is the question?', max_length=4000)
    question_category = models.ForeignKey(Category) 
    question_type = models.CharField('Question Type', max_length=50)
    question_comment = models.TextField(('Question Comments/Explanations', max_length=4000)
    question_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Category(models.Model):
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sub_topic = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

2)

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.TextField('What is the question?', max_length=4000)
    question_ sub_topic = models.ForeignKey(SubTopic) 
    question_type = models.CharField('Question Type', max_length=50)
    question_comment = models.TextField(('Question Comments/Explanations', max_length=4000)
    question_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class SubTopic(models.Model):
    sub_topic = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)

class Topic(models.Model):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain)

class Domain(models.Model):
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

In the case that the sub_topic field is not set I would be set to default=’none’ and blank=True

Can someone advise if any of the two solutions shown above would be a good implementation for what I want to achieve? If not what would be a good approach?

Comment: What you call **unique** is actually 1:n relation. If a topic can relate to more than one domain you'll need a **ManyToManyField** instead of **ForeignKey**.

Comment: In example 2 if subtopic is optional, then you'll end up with orphaned questions, because if they can't be assigned to a subtopic, consequently will not be assigned to topic and domain.

Comment: In example 1 you can't set `unique=True` for **domain** and you should set `blank=True` for **sub_topic**.

Comment: You seem to indicate that both would work with the observation mentioned in your post, correct? So which one is the best way to do it? I will lookup manyto many as I don't know much about it

Comment: The first example would work with the corrections I mentioned, but I don't like that solution at all. The data will be denormalized, very redundant and might cause some unwanted behaviour. The second example more advanced, but needs some adjustment. I'll write an answer later today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments to your question, the second example is more advanced than the first one. The problem here is that the subtopic is optional. That can be displayed like this:

Domain -> Topic -> (Subtopic)

A question can be part of a subtopic or of a topic. That means that you can't simply use a foreign key in `Question` pointing to `Subtopic`. My approach would be to make a question linked either to subtopic or topic. For this purpose I'd propose using Django [`contenttypes`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/).

The model `Question` could look like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField('What is the question?', max_length=4000)
    type = models.CharField('Question Type', max_length=50)
    comment = models.TextField(('Question Comments/Explanations', max_length=4000)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

What changes did we make? First we dropped the prefix *question* in the class attributes. It isn't necessary and it clutters up.
Other meaningful change we didn't make is maybe to reduce the `max_length` for `text` and `comment`. Do you really think you'd need 4000 characters for a question? For comparison a tweet length is 140 characters.

The most important thing we changed is the foreign key to `SubTopic`. We created a generic relation (`content_type`, `object_id`, `content_object`).
This means you can relate a question object to any model you have. In praxis this will be `SubTopic` or `Topic`.

The rest can stay with some slight changes:

```
class SubTopic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)

class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    domain = models.ManyToManyField(Domain)

class Domain(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

We have now `name` as attribute of every class, instead of repeating the class name as attribute. Think of this:

- Subtopic.name is better than Subtopic.sub_topic
- Domain.name is better than Domain.domain

Because a topic can belong to more than one domain (the topic Meteorology can be part of the domain Aviation, but also part of the domain Science) we changed the `ForeignKey` to `ManyToManyField`. Django will take care for creating an intermediary table in the database.

Another alternative would be to scrape the model `SubTopic`, create in `Question` a `ForeignKey` to `Topic` and change `Topic` like this:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    domain = models.ManyToManyField(Domain, related_name='topics')
    subtopic = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='subtopics')
```

EDIT:

Here is some further explanation of the alternative solution. In your question you have given some examples for domains, topics and subtopics:

- Aviation->Meteorology->Climate
- Aviation->Meteorology->Atmosphere
- Aviation->Mass and Balance

Meteorology, Climate, Atmosphere, Mass and Balance all are topics. For Climate (and similar for Atmosphere) you'd have the following properties:

```
Climate.name = 'Climate'
Climate.domains.all() = <QuerySet [<Domain: 'Aviation'>]>
Climate.subtopic = <Topic: 'Meteorology'>
```

The property name `subtopic` is maybe not very expressive, since it means here: Climate is subtopic of Meteorology. I added also a related name, so you could get the questions something like this:

```
aviation = Domain.objects.get(name='Aviation')
meteorology = aviation.topics.get(name='Meteorology')
# if there is a subtopic you want to query
climate = meteorology.subtopics.get(name='Climate')
climate.questions.all() # you have to set related name questions
# in the model Question in the foreign key field
# if case there are no subtopics
mass_and_balance = aviation.topics.get(name='Mass and Balance')
mass_and_balance.questions.all()
```

I hope this helps to clarify the approach.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have marked as accepted because I will at least one solution working. Regarding sub-topic have you noted that I propose default='none' rather than default=None? To me setting none as a string avoid the situation of orphan you mentioned earlier. I will test with conttentype as well as ForeignKey(Self) which I don't understand for now. At least I have something to work on so thanks again

Comment: @Fabou78 Even if you set `default='none'` for sub-topic wouldn't help, because in your original example 2. the question is related to sub-topic, and not to topic. So you wouldn't be able to assing questions to topics without sub-topics.